# I want to insert the data into an array but it shows a warning message that duplicates are not allowed

Tags: angularjs

```
$scope.data = {
   "items": [{
      id: 1,
      name: "Vijay",
      email: "vijay@gmail.com",
      mobile: "9090909090",
      salary: 98690
   }, {
      id: 2,
      name: "ajay",
      email: "ajay@gmail.com",
      mobile: "9190909090",
      salary: 98969
   }, {
      id: 3,
      name: "mahesh",
      email: "mahesh@gmail.com",
      mobile: "8090909090",
      salary: 78555
   }, {
      id: 4,
      name: "ganesh",
      email: "ganesh@gmail.com",
      mobile: "9099909090",
      salary: 48756
   }, {
      id: 5,
      name: "balu",
      email: "balu@gmail.com",
      mobile: "9880909090",
      salary: 98909
   }, {
      id: 6,
      name: "kapil",
      email: "kapil@gmail.com",
      mobile: "9090907790",
      salary: 76595
   }]
}

$scope.items = $scope.data.items;
$scope.addItem = function(item) {
      $scope.items.filter(function(el) {
         if (el.id !== item.id) {
            console.log(el.id, "xxxxxxxxxxxx inside if xxxxxxxxxxx", item.id);
            $scope.items.push(item);
            //  console.log($scope.items,item);
            $scope.item = {};
         } else {
            console.log("sdhjkkkkk inside else kkkkkkkkkkkkkkk")
            alert("already exist");
         }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you trying to push element on each iteration of 'filter' loop if id of your item !== item id of array element.
Also, filter is not what you need for this. It returns new array. 
You can use 'every' for this. For example:

```
$scope.addItem = function(item) {
  if (checkEquality(item, $scope.items)) {
    $scope.items.push(item);
  }
};

function checkEquality(element, array) {
  return array.every(function(item) {
    return item.id !== element.id;
  });
}
```